# Get username in model with extended user

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, serialization

At the moment, I get the user id when I create a new article. I would like also to have the username in the model (I'm using DRF with React, so it would save me a get request just for the username).

models.py:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, related_name='Article', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

serializers.py:

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        read_only=True, default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'user']

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs["user"] = self.fields["user"].get_default()
        return super().save(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
user = PublicProfileSerializer(
    read_only=True, default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())

class Meta:
    model = Article
    fields = ['id', 'title', 'user']

def save(self, **kwargs):
    kwargs["user"] = self.fields["user"].get_default()
    return super().save(**kwargs)
```

with PublicProfileSerializer:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
UserModel = get_user_model()

class PublicProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = [
            "id",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "username",
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below should get the username attribute from the user field.

```py
getattr(self.fields['user'], self.fields['user'].USERNAME_FIELD)
```